# VisualVM Version of OpenJDK is not supported

Tags: 22.04, openjdk

I have install VisualVM on my Ubuntu machine, and I'm getting this error when trying to open it:

`Version of OpenJDK is not supported. Please use the default-jdk.`

I have no idea on how to solve it

`java -version` outputs the following:

```
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Have you tried Java 11?

Comment: @DanielT nope. But Java 17 is used by the services I want to "debug" with VisualVM...

Comment: `apt show visualvm` shows `Depends: default-jdk (>= 2:1.11) | java11-sdk, libnb-platform18-java (>= 12.1), libvisualvm-jni` . You might need to manually download it from https://visualvm.github.io/download.html

Comment: @DanielT I must be really dumb but on the manual download page I can't see any ubuntu package... they only show Windows and macOS

Comment: @DanielT indeed I am dumb. I saw now the linux binary. Anyway it outputs the same error...

Comment: Works on a clean `opejdk-17-jdk` on 23.10. Are there multiple Java versions installed and what do you get for `type -a java` ?

Comment: @DanielT `java is /usr/bin/java` and `java is /bin/java`

Comment: So that looks normal for usrmerge, and I should have asked for `update-alternatives --list java` . I currently can't test 22.04, so here's something else you could try. You could download https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/ and put it in your PATH, reboot, then try visualvm again.

Comment: @DanielT `update-alternatives` outputs `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`